# Pasting a command line into VSCode's integrated terminal executes part of it prematurely

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

when I copy my code into terminal in VScode . terminal executes my code before my code finish copying.

```sh
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

how to turn off this feature
[image]

sorry my english is bad, i use google translate.

Answer (score 0):

Your integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code is running PowerShell, which doesn't support use of `\` as a line-continuation character.

Either use `` ` `` (a backtick), making sure that it is the very last character on the line, or paste the command as a *single* line.

Additionally, PowerShell doesn't understand `%USERPROFILE%` as an environment-variable reference (only `cmd.exe` does); use `$env:USERPROFILE` instead.

Therefore:

- With line continuation:

```sh
keytool -list -v `
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore $env:USERPROFILE\.android\debug.keystore
```

- Single-line:

```sh
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore $env:USERPROFILE\.android\debug.keystore
```